# Decreasing training learning curve

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I have made a learning curve that looks like this:

[image]

Why wouldn't it be more like both training and cross-validation score begin low
and both gradually increase with more samples? Why does one start high while the other
starts low? For example, this is how I thought it would look:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I cannot see any images

Comment: What is "score"? What kind of metric do you use?

Comment: take a look at this video to understand learning curves :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISBGFY-gBug

Comment: See also http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html#learning-curve, since this is tagged with scikit-learn

Answer (score 1):

Because a sufficiently powerful machine learning algorithm (together with nicely separable data), will have no problem correctly classifying a small number of data points. Of course that usually means it will be overfitting to those few points, which is why your training score is high and your cross-validation score low.